# TwentyTwenty no height after being hidden and then shown by a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have [Foundation TwentyTwenty](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) on my page but on first load, this content is hidden. After a button is clicked, it will be visible but occasionally, TwentyTwenty container doesn't have any height.

FireFox seems fine but chrome and IE doesn't have a height. On my computer right now, and I'm using IE 11 on Widows 7, IE works. Chrome doesn't. On other Windows 7 computers, IE and chrome doesn't work even with the latest versions.

Here's [the link](http://goo.gl/J4G9NX) to the site. Click on read all to view the TwentTwenty slider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
  // hide here after twentytwenty load in this div.
  $("#yalecontent").hide("fast");

  $(".openthis").click(function() {
    $("#yalecontent").show("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may well help someone else but I think I'm quite late for this one. Hiding the div before the twentytwenty script is initialized will have odd effects. You have to wait for the script to load, and then load the images afterwards. In your example, you would change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
```

*Then* hide the images after the initialization of the twentytwenty plugin. I think I read somewhere else to reinitialize the script by calling it after the images have loaded, but don't do that as it will add another UI layer ontop of the existing one.

Hope this helps someone else.